# Is there a way to make a user dbo for all AZURES SQL DBs?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a user who I have added to the following Azure SQL Server Roles-

```
##MS_DatabaseConnector##
##MS_DatabaseManager##
##MS_LoginManager##
```

I thought ##MS_DatabaseManager## would give them dbo access to all the databases. It turns out it will only give them dbo access to databases they create. Is there a way to have them be dbo on each database whether the create it or not?
Thanks

Comment: A `USER` is a database object; it can't access other databases. If you want someone to be able to connect them to be able to access all the database as an admin, you'll need to create a `LOGIN` in the Azure Portal with System Administrator privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/security-server-roles?view=azuresql) `MS_DatabaseManager` role in Azure SQL Database does not provide the user with dbo access to all databases If you want to access all database with one user you need to create login in master database
using below code:

```
Create Login <loginName> with password ='<Password>'
```

[image]

connect database with admins login

[image]

Create user in all databases with created login using below code:

```
CREATE USER <userName> FOR LOGIN <loginName>
```

And add the `DB_owner` role to the user using below code:

```
ALTER  ROLE  DB_OWNER ADD MEMBER <userName>
```

[image]

In this way you can access all the databases in the server. Otherwise as @Thom A said create a `LOGIN` in the Azure Portal with System Administrator privileges.